# Only Ancestor Queries are allowed inside of transactions

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

What is the reason why only Ancestor queries are allowed inside Transactions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ancestor queries restrict the result set to a specific entity group.  As a conceptual model, think of an entity group as a cluster of entities on a single machine; you can only run a transaction within a single machine.  XG transactions are 2pc processes spanning multiple separate machines.

Comment: What is its implication for example I have 3-Node AppEngine machine (say in my own cluster, for example I am using AppScale) when one request hits one node does it mean that the other 2 nodes when a request is made to access the same "entity" does it mean that the DAOT logic will fail?

Comment: I have no idea what AppScale does; you might try posting that as a separate question tagged with AppScale.  Also remember that this idea that each EG is stored in a separate database server instance is just a conceptual model; it doesn't necessarily work that way, but it helps to think of it so.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading the combination of two articles, it gives you a pretty good understanding of how transactions are handled on the datastore:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/life_of_write
https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/transaction_isolation

If you want to know how it works amongst a distributed network of datastore nodes, read up on the BigTable whitepaper.

http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable.html

The Datastore is built on top of BigTable, so understanding how BigTable works gives you a pretty good sense of what's going on in the datastore.